# Haxe-OpenFL Udp Sockets - sendTo() not working

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, haxe, udpclient

This is variable definition above the main function :

```
private var udpsocket:UdpSocket;
```

This is inside of create() function :

```
udpsocket = new UdpSocket();
udpSend("HEY!");
```

This is udpSend() function :

```
private function udpSend(msg:String):Void {
    var adres:Address = new Address();

    adres.host = new Host(Soket.ip).ip;
    adres.port = Soket.port;
    try{
        udpsocket.sendTo(Bytes.ofString(msg), 0, msg.length, adres);
    }catch (e:Dynamic) {
        trace(e);
    }
}
```

Soket.ip and Soket.port defined as static.
When i build, i got this error :

```
Custom(load.c(357) : Primitive not found : std@socket_send_to(5))
```

How can i solve this? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like that function isn't implemented on cpp, there is a PR open implementing it https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/pull/236

Comment: So i can't use udp sockets on my project?

Comment: I'm not really sure, you will need to wait until someone with better knowledge about this topic answers, sorry.

Comment: If you are using neko you will need to compile from source since none of the provided binaries include UDP sockets. https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/neko